# How do I use hashids on angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hashids

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252611/how-do-i-use-pure-javascript-library-hashids-js-on-angular/52253238#52253238)

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-hashids) is the only port to angular that I've seen. The thing is, it is no longer maintained and it doesn't provide a quick getting started tutorial on its read.me in GitHub. I also thought of using hashids.js directly but I am confused with the steps I follow.

So I would like to know if anyone used this on angular and how they did it. Thank you! :)

**Update**

I've tried importing the said ng port but it gave this error

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-hashids/index.ts
>           Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\FireCuda\Projects\angular\InformationAndEve
>           ntSystem\stiGoDashboard\node_modules\ng2-hashids\index.ts is missing from the Ty
>           peScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or
>            'include' property.
>           The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue In the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library
>            using the Angular Package Format.
>               at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\FireCuda\Projects\angular
>           \InformationAndEventSystem\stiGoDashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angu
>           lar_compiler_plugin.js:740:23)
>               at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\FireCuda\Projects\angular\InformationAndEventS
>           ystem\stiGoDashboard\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31)
>               at 
>               at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

**Second update**

I tried importing the library directly

```
import * as hash from '../../../../node_modules/hashids';
```

and tried this code
      let id = hash.encode(this.studentDocument.student_id_number);
      console.log(id);

But it throws this error, sad.

```
_node_modules_hashids__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.encode is not a function
```

I even tried this

```
declare var hash:any;
```

But it throws this error

```
hash is not defined
```

It seems that it needs updating before anyone can use this on angular.
Any tips on how to use a pure js library, especially this one, would be greatly appreciated!