# How do I use pure javascript library, hashids.js on angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hashids

I tried importing the library directly

```
import * as hash from '../../../../node_modules/hashids';
```

and tried this code

```
let id = hash.encode(this.studentDocument.student_id_number); console.log(id);
```

But it throws this error, sad.

```
_node_modules_hashids__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.encode is not a function
```

I even tried this

```
declare var hash:any;
```

But it throws this error

```
hash is not defined
```

Any tip would be greatly appreciated!
(a cont. of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251613/how-do-i-use-hashids-on-angular))

Comment: have you try to replace `import * as hash from '../../../../node_modules/hashids';
` by `require('hashids')` ?

Comment: Something like this, sir?
require('hashids');

Comment: How can I access the methods? Thank you for replying!

Comment: after require, just put `declare var hashids:any;` then consume as documentation.

Comment: It throws this error, ERROR ReferenceError: hashids is not defined. I guess it really has its quirks. Thanks for replying again sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the hashids object.

```
import * as hash from 'hashids';

const hashids = new hash();
const id = hashids.encode(348029348);
console.log(id);
```

Comment: Sir wingnod, I threw the code to the constructor, minus the import but this error pops up.  Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Comment: It didn't with import * as hash from 'hashids'; But worked with import * as hash from '../../../../node_modules/hashids/dist/hashids.min.js';